# How can I confim that a file was sent successfully via bluetooth using Android 4+

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have written an app that sends a file to a laptop via Bluetooth. I would like to be able to delete that file automatically after some confirmation that the file was sent successfully.

I get a Toast message from BlueTooth Share that the file was sent, but how can I detect this from my app?

Is there a callback that I can use for this?

Here is my method for sending the file using Android 4+

```
 File filename = new File(path + "/" + itemValue);
           Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filename);
           //send file via bluetooth
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("text/*");
           //this causes us to send via bluetooth only
           intent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send file"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the source, I see [`Constants.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/43f8ccf63a02b28be395fd223461f1421ea2aa99/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/Constants.java) and [`HandoverService.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/jb-mr1.1-dev/src/com/android/nfc/handover/HandoverService.java) which seem to indicate that a Broadcast is sent when the transfer is completed.

```
/** intent action used to indicate the completion of a handover transfer */
public static final String ACTION_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE =
        "android.btopp.intent.action.BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE";
```

and

```
/** intent extra used to indicate the success of a handover transfer */
public static final String EXTRA_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS =
        "android.btopp.intent.extra.BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS";

public static final int HANDOVER_TRANSFER_STATUS_SUCCESS = 0;
public static final int HANDOVER_TRANSFER_STATUS_FAILURE = 1;
```

In `HandoverService`:

```
if (action.equals(ACTION_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE)) {
    int handoverStatus = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS,
            HANDOVER_TRANSFER_STATUS_FAILURE);
    if (handoverStatus == HANDOVER_TRANSFER_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
```

So basically, you need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE`, and then check for the `EXTRA_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS` extra and see if it was success or failure.

Since these don't appear to be part of the public API, be warned that this could change in a future release.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and also the warning about this changing in a future release. Would a better way be to send the file myself and not delegate this work?

Comment: If you're able to do the file transfer yourself, I'd definitely recommend it. It's always safer not to rely on undocumented APIs. :) 

Another suggestion is that if the license is appropriate for your project, the Bluetooth app itself is open source and licensed under Apache 2.0: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/

Comment: I think I will go with your suggestion. I like that idea a lot better. I would rather stay inside public api's and just include the Bluetooth app. Very helpful. Thank you.