# Unable to receive BluetoothOppLauncherActivity broadcast events

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am sharing a file via `Bluetooth`. File has been sent successfully, but the problem is i am unable to receive any event when file has been sent completely. I have added receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` as

```
<receiver android:name=".FileSentReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.btopp.intent.action.TRANSFER_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And code to share file is as:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/file_to_sent.txt");
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

How can I receive file complete / decline events?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to register a BroadcastReceiver for `ACTION_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_DONE`, and then check for the `EXTRA_BT_OPP_TRANSFER_STATUS` extra and see if it was success or failure.

It seems that these don't appear to be part of the public API & this could change in a future release.

For details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920094/how-can-i-confim-that-a-file-was-sent-successfully-via-bluetooth-using-android-4)

Comment: I have tried these events but still unable to receive, it looks that those events can't be received from other applications.