# How to get event of sending status while sending file over bluetooth?

Tags: android, events, bluetooth, toast, android-bluetooth

I am sending a simple text file over Bluetooth to a second device. Based on whether I accept or decline the file in the receiving device, an OS level Toast message is displayed in the sending device, i.e. "File sent" or "File not sent". How can i get access to these events in the sending device?

Comment: Check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920094/how-can-i-confim-that-a-file-was-sent-successfully-via-bluetooth-using-android-4